# How to use window.location with Tauri?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, electron, tauri

I've got an onclick link in an svg that would link to another part of the website/program.  I used window.location.replace(...) in the onclick

`<example onClick(() => window.location.replace(...)) />`

and that works fine for the web browser - but it causes the Tauri application to just white screen.

I did a little searching and found something that said to use `window.eval(window.location.replace(...))` but that didn't work either unfortunately.

I was hoping to use a `<Link>` as a replacement as that seems better from what I've read, but I couldn't get it working in the onClick.

Is there a way to use window.location functions in tauri?  And if not is there a way I could use a `<Link>` in an onClick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `react-router` and using an element's `onClick` prop then you'll want to use the `history` object or `navigate` function to issue an imperative redirect. The `Link` component needs to be rendered into the DOM in order for *it* to be clicked, it can't be used in the `onClick` callback of another element.

### `react-router@5`

Import and use the [`useHistory`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

const Component = () => {
  ...

  const history = useHistory();

  ...

  <example onClick={() => history.replace(".....")} />
```

### `react-router@6`

Import and use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) hook:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const Component = () => {
  ...

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  <example onClick={() => navigate(".....", { replace: true })} />
```